# Hosting web page from STM32 device

Tags: microcontroller, embedded

My goal for my next project is to interface with a computer in order to stream some data as well as get some configuration parameters. I have been looking at using USB, UART to USB, and hosting a web page.

Hosting a webpage seems like the nicest solution seeing as all the user needs is an internet browswer, however I am very lost on how and where to start.

1. Will I be able to use a STM32
2. Will I be able to use WiFi instead of ethernet and which is easier?
3. Should I instead just use UART because this will be too complex?

Comment: USB-serial is usually the simplest, even though a pain for windows victims to install.  Ethernet or wifi require more complicated hardware, and a tricky process of getting network configuration into the embedded device.

Comment: Do you know of any good guides for ethernet/wifi? I am a fourth year EE student and I have over a year experience with firmware design but have not done a computer interface. I would like to do a webpage but I am very lost on where to start. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can get serial or SPI interface network modules, but a lot of people will hack a small linux-based router instead.  An STM32F4 could conceivably host a USB network dongle, but creating drivers may be a huge project.

Comment: Do you think you could give me some insight on how to store and display the HTML/CSS/Javascript information? Essentially a flow diagram type explanation?

Comment: I' m voting to close this question as off-topic because  it is not really electronics design

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the exact STM32 variant you're planning to use, but hosting a web page might very well be possible. If you're just making an one-off demo / proof of concept, you could consider using one of these:

Segger embOS/IP is available as evaluation version for various STM32 processors. See this page for some well documented & easily extendable examples:

https://www.segger.com/st-microelectronics.html

Segger has also USB RDNIS component available which would allow you to access the web server via USB, so you wouldn't need an Ethernet controller. I couldn't find any evaluation version though.

EmCraft has some system-on-module solutions running ucLinux available. They have a built-in web server which is easy to customize.

http://www.emcraft.com/products/224

ST Microelectronics has a code generator suite called STM32cubeMX. It might also offer a good starting point for developing web server.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

For stm32 can use rndis driver. I have seen the realization of the driver and the web server here: https://github.com/fetisov/lrndis, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W_o0lPivqsA

Comment: This is a very low-quality answer. If the pages you have linked to go away, the answer will be useless. Can you summarize the information found there for us?